# Authentication services

Tags: authentication, jakarta-ee

I have a web app (Java- and GWT-based), which requires an authentication mechanism (login, logout, password reset etc.).

I don't want to waste my time implementing it, so I'm looking for services, which allow the user to login to my web app using his existing accounts like Twitter, Facebook etc.

I found one such service called loginza.ru.

Are there any alternatives to it?

Thanks in advance

Dmitri

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use [OpenID](http://openid.net/) (like Stack Overflow)!  [Here's](http://chaoticjava.com/posts/using-openid-within-gwt/) a post on how to do it with GWT.

OpenID does require the user *have* an OpenID, but with google and others providing OpenID auth on top of their services, this is becoming easier and easier.

Answer (score 2):

Try SocialAuth. It provides login via twitter, facebook, openid, yahoo, google

This is the address:
http://code.google.com/p/socialauth/